# HP 3732 deskjet printer settings

Tags: printing

I found the driver for HP Deskjet 3740, hpcups 3.16.3, but no help and I didn´t found the answer from allready known answers. Does someone have any idea to get HP printer working ?

```
URI-> usb://HP/Deskjet%203700%20series?serial=CN73S3D1PG06H&interface=1
```

It is working on Win10 64bit with USB and Direct-B5-HP Deskjet 3700 series !
I am beginner and I desided to try Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my ThinkPad-T61 64-bit.
I began to like Ubuntu, but HP doesent have the support for HP Printer and because of that I am "forced" to go back Win10, but before going back I am askin your´s help.

Comment: you can get linux drivers here http://supporthp.net/hp-deskjet-3740-printer-drivers/

Comment: Printer is HP Deskjet 3732 and on cover of printer there is: HP Deskjet 3700 All-In-One series. HP Device Manager do not find USB !

Comment: did you try it? 3700 series should be similar. also install HPLIP from the software center

Comment: Weird. I work with HP Deskjet printers in Ubuntu for 10 years, never had any issue with it. Ubuntu just detects, installs and make it work. No need HP Manager.

Comment: I cannot se HP printer in "Disk" area. I can see Memory Stick in the same USB-port.

Comment: Now I have new HPLIP 3.17.9 and there is HP Deskjet 3700 series and printing and scanning is Ok with USB. Duplex, two side, is not working, so I think that I have to wait driver for 3732. Direct-mode would be nice also to have.